# How can i make the components function more efficient?

Tags: python, graph-theory

My implementation of the graph datastructure to find the number of components in the graph

```py
class Graph:     # This is class of the graph data structure
    def __init__(self, num_nodes, edges):
        self.num_nodes = num_nodes
        self.data = [[] for i in range(num_nodes)]
        for n1, n2 in edges:
            self.data[n1].append(n2)
            self.data[n2].append(n1)

    def bfs(self, root):      # using breadth first search algorithm
        queue = []
        discovered = [False] * len(self.data)
        distance = [None] * len(self.data)
        parent = [None] * len(self.data)

        discovered[root] = True
        distance[root] = 0
        queue.append(root)
        idx = 0

        while idx < len(queue):
            current = queue[idx]
            idx += 1

            for node in self.data[current]:
                if not discovered[node]:
                    discovered[node] = True
                    distance[node] = 1 + distance[current]
                    parent[node] = current
                    queue.append(node)

        return set(queue), distance, parent

    def components(self): # listing the components of the graph
        components = []
        for i in range (0, len(self.data)):
            component = self.bfs(i)[0]
            if component not in components:
                components.append(component)
        return components
```

I want to skip over repeating perfoming bfs on each and every node to find the connected components on a graph.

Comment: Apart from your question here, consider submitting your code to codereview.stackexchange.com, read their site guidelines first though! Point is, there are a few things to improve outside of your question. That said, put your code in triple backticks followed by the language to get the proper syntax highlighting here. I already tweaked that for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to skip over repeating perfoming bfs on each and every node to find the connected components on a graph.

That certainly is unnecessary. You need only run BFS once for every component in graph.

```
- SET CN = 0
- MARK every vertex unvisited
- LOOP V over vertices
       - IF V unvisited
           - DO BFS from V, marking vertices as they are visited
           - INCREMENT CN
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are scanning for connected nodes starting at *every* node, which is overkill. You can skip every node that you already visited in a previous scan.